# Multiple Domains, Single IP Blocked by Gmail

Tags: email, dns, gmail, postfix, spam-prevention

I have two domain names and 1 email server.

When I send an email from my server to my gmail account, and then view the original message, emails from both domains are stated to:

- Pass SPF
- Pass DKIM

But, the emails sent from the domain I used initially are correctly received in my inbox, while emails sent from the domain I set up second are sent to spam.

When I check rDNS in bash using 'host [domain.name]', both domain names return the correct IP address and mail handler domain name.

The greatest suspicion of the error I suspect is, when I view the original message in gmail, the first line states:

- `Message ID: <LongCharString@domain1.com>`

Where, for both domains, the domain following the @ is the domain I was initially using. In other words, both `Message ID:` fields for either domain contain the domain of only the first domain. If this is indeed the issue, is someone able to identify what causes this and how it could be changed ?

I'm not 100% sure this is the cause, so if anyone has any other ideas, thoughts are appreciated.

### Solution Attempts

I have added the clause:

```
include:domain2.com
```

to the SPF record of my initial domain. This hasn't solved the issue.

Yesterday, I was testing my initial domain with:
https://www.mail-tester.com/
Today, the service is stuck in a loading state after I click 'Then check your score'. This would help me in testing, could someone name an alternative or if this service is known to be down ?

### System Information

I am using Ubuntu, with postfix, imap and pop3 as my server. DKIM is handled by opendkim. My server host is IONOS. If any other system information would be helpful in diagnosis, please don't hesitate to ask.

## Update

Attempting to use 'mail-tester.com' again today and the site is working. All checks for my second domain are OK, except for the flag:

```
FROM_FMBLA_NEWDOM: From domain was registered in last 7 days
```

So I'm thinking it could be a case of waiting until 7 days has passed from my date of domain registration - hopefully the spam flag issue is resolved then.